# Get result from Stored Procedure then pass to WPF TextBox

Tags: sql, wpf

I have this stored procedure that executes fine:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GENERATETICKET] 
@RESULT AS VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @D AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @LASTTICKET AS VARCHAR(50) ;
DECLARE @NUM AS VARCHAR(50);
SET @LASTTICKET=(SELECT TOP 1 TICKETNO FROM tblTicket WHERE 
MONTH(ENTRYVEHICLE  ) = MONTH(@D ) ORDER BY TICKETNO DESC);
IF (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(@D),110) <> CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),YEAR(GETDATE()),110))--IF YEAR IS DIFFERENT, RESET SERIES
    BEGIN
        SET @NUM = '1'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN 
        IF ISNULL(@LASTTICKET,'1')  = '1'--IF MONTH IS DIFFERENT, RESET SERIES
            BEGIN
                SET @NUM ='1'
            END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
                SET @NUM = CAST(CAST (RIGHT(@LASTTICKET,5) AS INT) + 1 AS VARCHAR)
        END
    END

SET @RESULT = RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@D,101),2) + '-' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@D,101),2) + '-' + RIGHT('0000'+CAST(@NUM AS VARCHAR),5)
SELECT @RESULT
END
```

I have this Code but it returns null

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gsql.connectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_GENERATETICKET", con);

try
{
    con.Open();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter result = command.Parameters.Add("@RESULT", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    txtTicket.Text = (string)command.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value;
}
    catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: please try the answer it will resolve your issue , you forgot to execute command

Comment: btw, it should return 18-03-00002 because @LASTTICKET = 18-03-00001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there problem is there , you forgot to execute command

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

without executing command you want get result back.

also you forgot to add size for you varchar paramter , so add thing line

```
result.Size = 8000;
```

udpated in below code

---

you code will be , you need to use `using` to dispose things for you

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gsql.connectionString))
{
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_GENERATETICKET", con))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter result = command.Parameters.Add("@RESULT", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            result.Size = 8000;//add parameter size 
            result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();//this line need to be added 
            txtTicket.Text = (string)command.Parameters["@RESULT"].Value;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it throws an error that says:
String[0]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: @LeojayRull - what is error ?? remove this line from procedure `SELECT @RESULT` not needed

Comment: @LeojayRull - you are getting errro because you didnt sepcify the size in sqlparameter which of type varchar

Comment: String[0]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0 at command.ExecuteNonQuery();
I already removed `SELECT @RESULT` doesn't work

Comment: @LeojayRull - you need to add `result.Size = 8000;` ...check my answer

Comment: Adding the size of sqlparameter works! Thank you sir! @Pranay Rana

Comment: @LeojayRull - welcome..Please dont forget to make use of `using` that is needed to dispose connection once used

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are a good practice but for output you cannot have SQL injection (that I know of).

```
con.Open();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
txtTicket.Text = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

For size you can use this syntax:

```
SqlParameter result = command.Parameters.Add("@RESULT", SqlDbType.VarChar, 800);
```

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'` at `txtTicket.Text = command.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: @LeojayRull Just cast it to string.